# invalid cross-thread access When calling IAP function in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am integrating In App Purchase using Cordova Plugin for Windows Phone 8.0
I have added a function in plugin called PurchaseProduct that will be called in JS Cordova project.

```
namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
...............

public async void PurchaseProduct(string options)
{
   string productId = JSON.JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options)[0];
     ......
    try
    {
       await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId, false);
       ........
    }
............
```

Calling below line is working very well.
**listing = await Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();**

but When I called
**await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId, false);**
exception occurred as below.

**invalid cross-thread access**

I have no idea what happened now.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry.
I've fixed this ridiculous one.

used aysnc keyword.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   functionA();
});

.....
public async void functionA(string options)
{
.....
   await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId, false);
.....
}
```